# Regex validation of folder path with unknown depth of nested directories

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple regex `^\\{2}[a-z0-9?_?]*\\{1}[a-z0-9?_?]*$` that can validate folder paths of the type `\\foo_bar1\foo_bar_2`.

The problem is that the complete path is created by the user using a form and it is unknown how deep the user might want to nest directories. Regardless, I want to make sure that the path is validated, for example, the user might want to create a path like `\\foo_bar1\foo_bar_2\foo_bar_3\foo_bar_4\foo_bar_n`.

Is there a way I can generalize the `\\{1}[a-z0-9?_?]*` part of the regex for the above problem for `n` number of nested directories?

Comment: What did you try to achieve with `?_?`? Looking at your example I guess [`^\\\\\w+(?:\\\w+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/RGbG70/1) will work.

Comment: `?_?` numbers and underscores can be optional in the folder path, however no other special characters

Comment: Then the given regex would work I guess since `\w` is shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: @JvdV yes, just tested, it works perfectly, what is `?:` doing though? also, if you feel like it, could you please write a short answer and I can accept it :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to find a pattern that would accept alphanumeric characters and underscores, you could simply make use of the `\w+` shorthand to match any word-character:

```
^\\\\\w+(?:\\\w+)*$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bts86o/1):

- `^` - Start-line anchor.
- `\\\\` - Two escaped (therefor literal) backslash characters.
- `\w+` - 1+ Word-characters.
- `(?:` - Open a non-capture group:

  - `\\\w+` - A single literal backslash (`\\`) followed by 1+ word-characters (`\w+`).
  - `)*` - Close non-capture group and match it 0+ times.